# UITapGestureRecognizer not working on iOS9

Tags: ios, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, xcode7, ios9

I have an application which uses `UITapGestureRecognizers` which seem to not work in iOS9 Beta 2.

They are successfully calling

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
  NSLog(@"shouldReceiveTouch");
  return YES;
}
```

but it doesn't hit any of the other UITapGesture delegate methods.

When I run the same application (from Xcode 7) on a device running on iOS 8, it works as expected.

Has anyone else hit this?

Here is how I initialise the UITapGestureRecognizer.
[image: TapGestureRecognizerSetup]

**Edit**
If I create the UITapGestureRecognizer in code instead of in the ViewController xib it works fine, so there's something up with the xib parsing in iOS9 or something.

```
_tapGesture2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onMainViewTap:)];
_tapGesture2.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
_tapGesture2.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:_tapGesture2];
```

**Edit2**
If I deleted the GestureRecognizer in the XIB and added it back in again using XCode 7, it also worked.
When I did this, it added `<pressTypeMask key="allowedPressTypes"/>` into the xib under the UITapGestureRecognizer.

Comment: did you set your view's property 'User interaction enabled' to YES ? maybe view does not properly handle touches

Comment: It's set to YES, but good idea :).

Comment: I've had the same problem with two different UITapGestureRecognizers in the app, both of which work fine in iOS 8.

Comment: Another point - UISwipeGestureRecognizers seem to be working fine.

Comment: the only one idea - check tapgesturerecognizer's delegate, is it ok?

Comment: That's what I said in the text. The 'shouldReceiveTouch' is called, but nothing else.

Comment: strange, downloading xcode 7 beta :)

Comment: See you in an hour or so. Takes a while for that and installing iOS9.

Comment: i've installed, could you write, what methods exectly did not call?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html

Comment: All except - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer * nonnull)gestureRecognizer        shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch * nonnull)touch

Comment: Can confirm this. I have older example projects with IB Gesture Recognizers that won't work, and just adding that obscure `<pressTypeMask key="allowedPressTypes"/>` line to their entries in the .storyboard file fixes their behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that iOS9 looks for a `<pressTypeMask key="allowedPressTypes"/>` line in the xml of the gesture recognizer and the tap recognizer doesn't work without it.
To fix you can either build your recognizers in code, add that line into the xml or delete and re-add the gesture recognizer in Xcode 7, which will properly add the `pressTypeMask` into the xml.

I wonder if apple will fix iOS9 to work without that line in the XML, but for now, this is an easy fix.

Comment: Reported this as a bug to Apple.

Comment: Can you tell me more where you want to insert <pressTypeMask key = "allowedPressTypes" />, please?

Comment: @Roman I'm not seeing how i can reproduce this on the latest version of Xcode. Are you having issues with this?

Comment: @yerforkferchips, yes, I have updated your project running iOS 8 to iOS 9.2 (swift 2.1). Does not work UITapGestureRecognizer. Help me please! If you create a new project from scratch, everything works.

Comment: Try and remove the tap gesture and add it back again and then compare how the xml changes. Alternatively you can create the tap gesture programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well, specifically when trying to get both my buttons and views w/ tap gestures within a table cell to respond to a click whose layout was defined in a xib. Worked fine on iOS 8 & 10, but not 9. The actual problem was that I added those to a custom uiview and assigned the view's class to my UITableViewCell subclass, rather than use a `Table View Cell` object within IB. Thus I did not add my subviews to the `contentView` that the IB object gives you, causing me the problem. The fix was to redo the xib to use the Table View Cell as my root, so I could attach my subviews to the Content View.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing all optional delegate of UIGestureRecognizer will work.

Answer (score -1):

I checked it via Xcode-7 beta 2

I've created vc with gesturerecognizer and create outlets for property and action. in viewDidload setted delegate, like this:
[image]

All methods, that was called during debug - i've marked //called

I received events to the next methods:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    print("worked")
    // called
    return true
}

 func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
 {
    //called
    print("worked")
    return true
}


 func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
 {
    print("worked")
    //called
    return true
}
```

Try recreate project as i mentioned and check all your outlets and delegate

Hope this helps

Comment: I built up a simple project as you did, and it seems that everything works fine there, but in my existing application, it never hits any of the other delegate methods except `shouldReceiveTouch`