# TapGestureRecognizer not calling selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

So I have a custom view that I am creating many of in a for-loop in my viewcontroller. While they're being created, I'm calling this method on each of them:

```
-(void)setUpStuff{
    //Random setup code
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self   action:@selector(tileSelected:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}
```

And this is the selector it should be calling:

```
-(void)tileSelected{
    NSLog(@"Why am I not working?");
    [self.delegate tileSelected:self];
}
```

It's probably worth mentioning that this customView has an imageView and label embedded within it. I've tried adding the gesture recognizer to the imageView and making sure that the imageView is being brought to the very front, however, that doesn't work either.. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe your problem has something to do with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049033/uitapgesturerecognizer-not-working-on-ios9) ?

Comment: No luck, I'm setting it up programmatically just like he said was doing when he was  able to get it to work for him D:

Answer (score 1):

Your selector call is wrong

it should be:

```
tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self   action:@selector(tileSelected)];
```

without the :

Comment: Where are you calling setUpStuff ?

Comment: I'm calling it in my ViewDidLoad in a separate view controller that is creating an array of this custom view. In the for loop where I'm creating them, I'm calling setUpStuff on each customView as I'm setting it's other properties.

Comment: Did you make your customView conform to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`?

Comment: Does it have required delegation methods?

Answer (score 0):

Firts of all you need to set the view's user interaction enable on which you adding gesture and also your selector is including `:` at end of method that means  you need to add parameter in method or just remove : from end of your selector.

Comment: I'm calling enable user interaction on self which is a view. I've also tried it without the colon and had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your tileSelected func to :`

```
-(void)tileSelected:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture{
    NSLog(@"Why am I not working?");
   [self.delegate tileSelected:self];
}
```

Comment: No luck after adding that :/

Comment: @DemetriP you add gestureRecognizer to your custom view , when you tap your imageView, the gesture wouldn't be triggered.

Comment: I've tried adding it to the imageView within the custom view but haven't had any luck with that either