# UIGestureRecognizer not working on Xcode 7.2 / iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uigesturerecognizer

UIGestureRecognizer not working on Xcode 7.2 / iOS 9.2 when I upgrade the project from Swift 1.2 iOS 8 to Swift 2.1 iOS 9.2.
If you create a new project, everything works.
I know for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31049033/uitapgesturerecognizer-not-working-on-ios9) but I do not know exactly where to insert and how this code will affect on work the application in the next iOS update.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
    viewMap.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    self.startLocationUpdates()   
}
@IBAction func longDetected(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    print("longPreesDetected")
}
@IBAction func panDetected(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    print("panDetected")
}
```

[image: UILongPressGestureRecognizer]

[image: UILongPressGestureRecognizer]

[image: UILongPressGestureRecognizer]

Comment: where did u set the delegate for gesture recogniser ?

Comment: I use [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_8_Swift_Gesture_Recognition_Tutorial) tutorial for UIGestureRecognizer

Comment: try to give recogniser.delegate=self; and mention <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> at the interface section of ur veiw controller