# UITapGestureRecognizer not working on older version of ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm working on a view that has a subview which outlet is viewRect. I programmatically added `UITapGestureRecognizer` on that view to perform a task.
It works fine on ios 10.3.1 (iPhone 5) but not in iOS 9.2.1 (iPhone 5).

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *mTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer  alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showView)];
[mTapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[self.viewRect addGestureRecognizer:mTapGestureRecognizer];
self.viewRect.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

method to respond

```
-(void)showView {

NSLog("tapped on view");

}
```

Can't figure out why this not working.

Comment: edit scheme debug <==> release worked for me. please check

Comment: Below link may be useful to you   http://stackoverflow.com/a/31158277/5184217  and add mTapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;